What's the difference between the different types of "control"
I've embarked myself into an "action in robotics" journey, and I'm currently having troubles to understand the main differences between the different types of "controls" listed below.

Motion control vs Position control vs Force control
Compliance vs other controls
Admittance vs Impedance controls

I'm also trying to understand which one is related to others and whether they share "hierarchical" relationships with each others.

Found this in the Springer Handbook of Robotics 2nd Edition, by Oussama Khatib, on page 197:

Special cases of impedance and admittance control are stiffness
control and compliance control, respectively, where only the static
relationship between the end-effector position and orientation
deviation from the desired motion and the contact force and moment is
considered. Notice that, in the robot control literature, the terms
impedance control and admittance control are often used to refer to
the same control scheme; the same happens for stiffness and compliance
control. Moreover, if only the relationship between the contact force
and moment and the end-effector linear and angular velocity is of
interest, the corresponding control scheme is referred to as damping
control.

